# Probability of picking animal from pond

Tags: probability

A bit confused by this problem.

Joe and Marcy have two distinguishable ponds.  Initially, each of the ponds contains four ducks and five geese.  Joe first picks a bird uniformly at random from the left pond and moves it to the right pond.  Then, Marcy picks a bird uniformly at random from the right pond. What is the probability that  Marcy picks a duck?

Do we work with conditional probabilities for this problem where we have to calculate the probabilities that Marcy picks a duck given Joe picks a ducks vs when he picks a goose?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need conditional probabilities.The second event 
Marcy picks a duck is dependent on first event ,which bird was transferred earlier by Joe. (duck or goose). So 
$P(Marcy picks duck)=P(Joe picks goose and Marcy picks duck)+P(Joe picks duck and Marcy picks duck)=P(Marcy picks duck | Joe picks goose) . P(Joe picks goose) + P(Marcy picks duck | Joe picks duck) . P(Joe picks duck).
=5/9*4/10 +4/9*5/10$